# sorting divs by id on two levels using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, sorting, dom

i looked through sorting with `jQuery`, but i need to sort in **two** levels.

sorting both levels, top and child levels alphabethically

my simple `HTML` structure is this:

```
<div id="contentObjects">
<div id="Blue" class="sort1">
  <div>
    Blue
  </div>

  <div id="Triangle" class="Blue_sort2">
    <h3>Triangle</h3>

    <div>
      internalName: b_triangle
    </div>

    <div>
      displayName: blue Triangle
    </div>

    <div>
      size: 2
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="Ball" class="Blue_sort2">
    <h3>Ball</h3>

    <div>
      internalName: b_ball
    </div>

    <div>
      displayName: blue Ball
    </div>

    <div>
      size: 5
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="Red" class="sort1">
  <div>
    Red
  </div>

  <div id="Cube" class="Red_sort2">
    <h3>Cube</h3>

    <div>
      internalName: r_cube
    </div>

    <div>
      displayName: red Cube
    </div>

    <div>
      size: 5
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

after document is ready i execute this `JavaScript`:

```
function sortAll() {
    var arrayOfClassIds = $.map($(".sort1"), function(n, i){
              return n.id;
            });
    var arrayOfSubClassIds;

    console.log(arrayOfClassIds);
    $.each($('.sort1'), function() {
        var _id = $(this).attr('id');
        var _parent = $(this);
        arrayOfSubClassIds = $.map($("."+_id+"_sort2"), function(n, i){
              return n.id;
            });

            var arrayOfSortedSubClassIds = arrayOfSubClassIds.sort();
            console.log(arrayOfSortedSubClassIds);
            // start sorting the second level

            $.each(arrayOfSortedSubClassIds, function(i, v) {
                console.log("appending "+v+" to "+_parent.attr('id'))
                // get element with id v and append it to the parent
                $(v).appendTo(_parent);
            });
    });
}
```

on my console the log looks good:

```
["Blue", "Red"]
["Ball", "Triangle"]
appending Ball to Blue
appending Triangle to Blue
["Cube"]
appending Cube to Red
```

so what i expected was that there is

```
Blue with Ball and Triangle, then Red with Cube.
```

but actually the result is

```
Blue with Triangle and Ball, then Red with Cube.
```

please point me to my mistake.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the last loop, you are only iterating over the Id's and trying to append Ids whereas you should append the DOM elements with those Id's

Try

```
 $('#' + v).appendTo(_parent);
```

See working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xGfYu/)

Comment: you are right! but i just noticed another mistake! i did not sort the first level! ;-) so if i move red above blue, it does not get sorted, but with your answer i'll fix it. THANKS!